# Let X be a random variable with the following p.m.f. f(x) = cx(4 − x), x = 1, 2, 3

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with the following p.m.f. $f(x) = cx(4 − x), x = 1, 2, 3$
and zero, otherwise.

(i) Find c

(ii) Find $E(X)$ and $Var(X).$

(iii) Find the moment generating function.

(iv) Draw a graph of the probability histogram of the pmf of $X$

I was able to find the value for c by doing $1=c(1(4-1) + 2(4-2) + 3(4-3))$ which gives $c = 1/10.$

Comment: $c=\frac{1}{10}$ IMHO

Comment: oops you're right.

Comment: For part (ii) use the standard formulae

Comment: For E(X) =μ =  Σap(a) so I would do ((2/3)(1/10)(2/3)^(2/3)) = 0.0508761885579. Is that correct?

Comment: @KGT No.  Why would you even...?  $\mathsf E(X)~=~\sum_{a=1}^3 af(a)~=~1f(1)+2f(2)+3f(3)$

Comment: Sorry just a little lost. Not very experienced with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what you do is we know $E(x)=x(f(x))$
And V$ar(x)=x^2(f(x))-(E(x))^2$

All you do is plug the numbers in and its very easy from then on

Comment: Please don't mislead KGT, the student appears confused enough as is.

Answer (score 0):

i) Yes, $c=1/10$, not $c=1/11$ as originally stated.

ii) from iii)

iii) $M_{X}(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=e^{t}*3/10+e^{2t}*4/10+e^{3t}*3/10$

$M_{X}'(0)=(3+8+9)/10=2$ and $M_{X}''(0)=(3+16+27)/10=46/10$

Comment: Im a little lost at how you got part 3.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ is expectation of $e^{tX}$, where $X$ is your r.v. You have the p.m.f.

Comment: @Jan I'm starting to suspect KGT does not know the definition of expectation or, at least, does not grok how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

(I) So you found $c=1/10$ by using $\mathsf E(X^0)=1$ knowing that $$\mathsf E(X^n) = c(1^{n+1}(4-1) + 2^{n+1}(4-2) + 3^{n+1}(4-3))$$

(II) You can then find $\mathsf E(X)$, and $\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2$

(III) The MGF is $\mathsf M_X(s)=\mathsf E(e^{sX}) =\sum_{x=1}^3 e^{sx}f(x)$

(IV) Just plot the graph of $f(x)\text{ v.s. }x$ as a histogram.

---

The expectation of a discrete random variable, is the weighted average.

In this case $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(g(X)) ~=~& \sum_{x=1}^3 f(x)g(x) \\[1ex] ~=~& f(1)g(1)+f(2)g(2)+f(3)g(3) \\[1ex]~=~& c (3g(1)+4g(2)+3g(3))\end{align}$$

Everything else in this question is just applying this to various functions $g$.   For instance, you found $c=1/10$ by using $\mathsf E(1)=1$ and so:

$$\begin{align}1 ~=~& c (3+4+3)\end{align}$$

Though it seems you did not quite grasp from where this expression came.

Then the expectation of $X$ is simply:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~=~& \tfrac 1{10} (3\cdotp 1+4\cdotp 2+3\cdotp 3)\\[1ex]~=~& 2\end{align}$$

(Aside: Which should be unsurprising, due to the symmetry of the probability mass function.)

Then you can either use $\mathsf {Var}(X) = \mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2$ or $\mathsf {Var}(X)=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))^2)$ to find the variance.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, almost got most of it, just wondering how you got E(X^n) = c(1^{n+1}(4-1) + 2^{n+1}(4-2) + 3^{n+1}(4-3)). How do you know which x you add the n+1 to?

Comment: By definition of expectation: $\mathsf E(X^n) ~=~ \sum_x x^n f(x) ~ = ~ \sum_{x=1}^3 x^n\cdot x(4-x)~=~\sum_{x=1}^3 x^{n+1} (4-x)$ @KGT